# Is one database (mysql) connection per user sufficient?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I am just getting into building web applications with PHP and MySQL.

My question is whether I should open and close a new database connection in each script I have, or whether I should reuse a static connection set up in an included file.

I have a file `database.inc.php` which defines a class `Database` with connect and error-reporting functions. I use the following variables:

```
private static $db_host = 'localhost'; 
private static $db_name = 'dbname'; 
private static $db_user = 'user'
private static $db_pass = 'password' //placeholder

public static $conn;
```

with the following connect function

```
public static function connect()
{
    if(!self::$conn){
        self::$conn = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_pass, self::$db_name);
        if(!self::$conn){
            self::error(self::$conn);
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

At the bottom of the file I create a database connection:

```
//instantiate class
$database = new Database;
//establish connection
$database::connect();
//return connection
$mysqli = $database::$conn;
```

In each of my files I include `database.inc.php`. So in each script (such as a login and register script) I reuse this same connection. In light of this, should I open a new connection in each script, or reuse this same one?

Comment: By virtual of the way PHP web pages work you are opening a connection each time any script runs, each script is a distinct execution

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are using new connection every time because `PHP` will not share your static variable between requests and connection will be closed on the end of each request.

You can read about persistent connections in `mysqli_*` [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) and decide if you want to use it.